# access query from different table with sum, group by

Tags: php, sql

I have the following columns and data on two tables named "tbl_stock" and "tbl_sale"

- tbl_stock

| id | stock_yard_name | stock_net_weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Asam Bangle | 31000 |
| 2 | Barek Building | 32000 |
| 3 | Asam Bangle | 32050 |

- tbl_sale

| id | sale_yard_name | sale_net_weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Asam Bangle | 31000 |
| 2 | Barek Building | 31200 |

I want to make a summary like the picture
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmUn1.png)

How can I query correctly

Here's how I tried

```
<?php
    $query  = "SELECT stock_yard_name, SUM(stock_net_weight) AS stock_net, SUM(tbl_sale.sale_net_weight) AS sale_net
              FROM tbl_stock LEFT JOIN tbl_sale
              ON tbl_stock.stock_yard_name = tbl_sale.sale_yard_name
              GROUP BY stock_yard_name
              ";
$post = $db->select($query);
        if ($post) {
          while ($result = $post->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
<tr>
  <td>
    <label><?php echo $result['stock_yard_name']; ?></label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php echo $result['stock_net']; ?><span> KG</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php echo $result['sale_net']; ?><span> KG</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php $balanced = ($result['stock_net']-$result['sale_net']); ?>
    <?php echo $balanced; ?><span> KG</span>
  </td>
</tr>
<?php }} ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: What is the issue? Are you encountering errors? Different results? Also, you're joining on `tbl_sale.yard_name`, but according to the sctructure you've presented, it should be `tbl_sale.sale_yard_name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you what you are looking for.

```
    select distinct stock_yard_name, stock, sale
    from (
    select stock_yard_name , sum(stock_net_weight)  stock
    from table1 
    group by stock_yard_name) t1 
    join (
    select sale_yard_name,  sum( sale_net_weight) sale
    from  table2
      group by sale_yard_name
    ) t2 on stock_yard_name = sale_yard_name
```

Comment: With your help, I was able to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
select ref.stock_yard_name,ref.stock_net_weight as stock, ref.sale_net_weight as sale,
ref.stock_net_weight - ref.sale_net_weight as advance
from(
select st.stock_yard_name as stock_yard_name, sum(st.stock_net_weight) stock_net_weight, sa.sale_net_weight
from tbl_stock st
inner join 
(
  select sale_yard_name, sum(sale_net_weight) sale_net_weight
  from tbl_sale
   group by sale_yard_name
 ) sa on (st.stock_yard_name = sa.sale_yard_name)
 group by st.stock_yard_name,sa.sale_net_weight
  )ref
order by ref.stock_yard_name asc
```